# How make circular network svg with flutter?

Tags: dart, svg, flutter-layout

It has been two days and not able to make a circular border for network svg image , I have tried all widgets who makes border circular like `Container()`,`CircleAvatar()`, and `ClipRRect()`, these are not working with network svg image `(SvgPicture.network())`

Expected view:

[image]

Note: for svg image , used [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) plugin.

here is the piece of code which I have tried:

```
Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 30,
                        width: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200),
                          child: SvgPicture.network(
                            controller.appCountry.value.flag!,
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
```

Actual output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73501371/9628990) and this below code work for me

```
SizedBox(
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1000),
        child: SvgPicture.network(
            countryList[index].image ?? '',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
    ),
),
```

result of this svg url : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Flag_of_Iran.svg

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please review this solution, it may help you

```
 ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1000.0)),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 10.h,
            width: 10.h,
            child: SvgPicture.network(
              "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Flag_of_Iran.svg",
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use [ClipOval](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html), with `CustomClipper` so you can modify the values.

```
SizedBox(
      width: 30.0,
      height: 30.0,
      child: ClipOval(
          clipper: MyOvalClipper(),
          child: SvgPicture.network(
            controller.appCountry.value.flag!,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
          ),
      ),
    );
```

custom clipper : `MyOvalClipper` :

```
class MyOvalClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    // TODO: implement getClip
    //modify value here based on your need
    //size width = 30.0, and height = 30.0 regardless of child size its don't matter
    var rect = const Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0);
    return rect;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me your time but it's not working properly